# Import csv to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

**Here is my code to import my csv to mysql database:**

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='jeremy_db')
file = open('C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\test.csv', 'rb')  # open the file in read binary mode
csv_data = csv.reader(file)
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1, vsdt,trendx,notes )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s")',row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

**It is giving me error:**

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trendMICRO\Desktop\OJT\import.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1, vsdt,trendx,notes )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s")',row)
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

I followed the instruction here: [Connect to mysql with python and upload csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757548/connect-to-mysql-with-python-and-upload-csv)

Comment: So name 'cursor' is not defined... because it is not defined? Try `cursor = cnx.cursor()`

Comment: You never define `cursor`.  You may want to look into using `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: Also mydb is not defined in your example. Pls rework it.

Comment: then gives me NameError: name 'mydb' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create the cursor itself. Also you mixed up variable names. *commit* is only for a MySQLConnection.

```
import csv
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='jeremy_db')
file = open('C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\test.csv', 'rb')  # open the file in read binary mode
csv_data = csv.reader(file)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1, vsdt,trendx,notes )' 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s")',row)

# close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```